# Load multiple jqgrid on same page

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I try to use two different jqgrid on the same page with the mvc application, tables are using diferent URL to load data and diferent names. It's possible use multiple jqgrid on same page!?!?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATED**: First thanks for the quick response

The problem continue after I've change the ids as you told me!
Here is my code:

Javasrcipt :

First Grid :

```
jQuery("#listMedicosTODO").jqGrid({
    url: '/Medico/LoadToDoMedicos/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Cod.', 'Titulo', 'Estado', 'Ultima Actualização'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'CodRelatorio', index: 'CodRelatorio', width: 50, align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'TituloRelatorio', index: 'TituloRelatorio', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: true },
        { name: 'EstadoRelatorio', index: 'EstadoRelatorio', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: false },
        { name: 'DataUltimaActualizao', index: 'DataUltimaActualizao', width: 100, align: 'left', hidden: false, sortable: false }
    ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
    caption: 'Tarefas Pendentes Médicos',
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var data = $("#listMedicosTODO").getRowData(id);
        alert("select row " + data.CodRelatorio);
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        alert("Load Complete");
        //$('#list').setGridParam({ url: '/PesquisarRelatorios/GetGridData/' });
    },
    gridComplete: function () { alert("Grid Complete"); },
    beforeRequest: function () { },
    viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
    autoheight: true
}).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: false });
```

Second Grid :

```
jQuery("#listaAssistentesTODO").jqGrid({
    url: '/Medico/LoadToDoAssistentes/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Cod.', 'Titulo', 'Assistente', 'Estado', 'Ultima Actualização'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'CodRelatorio', index: 'CodRelatorio', width: 50, align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'TituloRelatorio', index: 'TituloRelatorio', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: true },
        { name: 'Assistente', index: 'Assistente', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false },
        { name: 'EstadoRelatorio', index: 'EstadoRelatorio', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: false },
        { name: 'DataUltimaActualizao', index: 'DataUltimaActualizao', width: 100, align: 'left', hidden: false, sortable: false }
    ],
    pager: jQuery('#page2'),
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50],
    sortname: 'CodRelatorio',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
    caption: 'Tarefas Pendentes Assistentes',
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var data = $("#listaAssistentesTODO").getRowData(id);
        alert("select row " + data.CodRelatorio);
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        alert("Load Complete");
         //$('#list').setGridParam({ url: '/PesquisarRelatorios/GetGridData/' });
    },
    gridComplete: function () { alert("Grid Complet"); },
    beforeRequest: function () { },
    viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
    autoheight: true
}).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: false });
```

Server endpoint :

1º

```
if(list != null)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords =  list.Count ;
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    var jsonData = new
                       {
                           total = totalPages,
                           page,
                           records = totalRecords,
                           rows = (from item in list
                                   select new
                                              {
                                                  i ="a" + item.CodRelatorio,
                                                  cell = new[]
                                                             {
                                                                item.CodRelatorio ,
                                                                item.TituloRelatorio,
                                                                item.Assistente ,
                                                                "Em Elaboração",
                                                                item.DataUltimaActualizao
                                                             }

                                             }).ToArray()
                        };


    return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

2º end point

```
if (list != null)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = list.Count;
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (from item in list
                select new
                {
                    i = "b"+ item.CodRelatorio,
                    cell = new[]
                                 {
                                    item.CodRelatorio ,
                                    item.TituloRelatorio,
                                    "Em Elaboração",
                                    item.DataUltimaActualizao
                                 }

                }).ToArray()
    };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This code contain your recomendations

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to use more as one jqGrid on one page. The most important thing which you should know is that `id`s which you posted from the server **must be different** in both grids. For example if you need for the first grid the id=1234 and the same for the second grid you can use `"a1234"` for the first grid and `"b1234"` for the second one.

If you will continue to have problems with two grids you should post the definition (JavaScript code) of the both grids and the test JSON or XML data with which you have problems.

**UPDATED**: Your main error is that you don't set and `id` on the server side. Instead of that you set `i` property which is unknown and which will be ignored. If no `id` is defined jqGrd try to use integers: "1", "2", ... values as the ids. Such "id-fix" works in case of one grid on the page, but not with two grids.

So you have to change `i ="a" + item.CodRelatorio` and `i = "b"+ item.CodRelatorio` to `id ="a" + item.CodRelatorio` and `id = "b"+ item.CodRelatorio`.

To tell the trust in [the demo example](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) posted by Phil Haack was the same writing error, but it is fixed at Mar 06, 2011 (see the comments on the page).

Another small changes which you should do are

1. remove [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) jqGrid parameter `imgpath`. It is not used since many years.
2. instead of unknown parameters `autowidth: true` and `autoheight: true` you probably wanted to use `height:'auto'`.
3. it is better to use `pager:'#page1'` and `pager:'#page2'` instead of `pager: '#page1'` and `pager: '#page2'`.
4. The first grid don't has the column with the name `'Id'`. So you should replace `sortname: 'Id'` jqGrid option to for example `sortname: 'CodRelatorio'`.

I recommend you to read the "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644). You can download [the example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) from the answer and use it as the template for your application.

Comment: The problem continue after I've change the ids as you told me!

Comment: @mastervv: You should read my answer: "If you will continue to have problems with two grids you should **post the definition (JavaScript code) of the both grids and the test JSON or XML data** with which you have problems".

Comment: I post javascript code and server side code, please take a  look at it!!

Comment: @mastervv: If you continue to have problems I recommend you to post (modify your original question and append more information) JSON data which will be posted from the server for both grids. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch the real data returned by the server. Then one will be able to reproduce your tests and help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Small notice: 1234 is not a valid HTML identifier, it should not start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use multiple Jqgrid in a single page, but have to give different Jqgrid IDs.

See below code. The working Example,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#datagrid").jqGrid({    //////////// 1st Grid
            url: "service url",
            //url: "service url",
            type: "GET",
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            datatype: "json",
            //colNames:['Id','MID','Status','DocNo','VendorID','InvoiceNo','VendorName','Amount','Type','DocDate','DueDate','ClDoc','Texxt','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Comb','Comments'],

            colNames:['Id','MID','Status','VendorID','VendorName','InvoiceNo','DocDate','Amount','DocNo','Type','DueDate','ClDoc','Text','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Process','Comb','Comments'],
            colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:50,sortable:true},
    {name:'mid',index:'mid', width:50, sortable:true},
    {name:'status',index:'status', width:70, sortable:true},
    {name:'vendorid',index:'vendorid', width:90, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'vendorname',index:'vendorname', width:170, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'invoiceno',index:'invoiceno', width:130, sortable:false,align:"left"},   
    {name:'docdate',index:'docdate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, sortable:false,align:"Right"},
    {name:'docno',index:'docno', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'typee',index:'typee', width:50, sortable:false},
    {name:'duedate',index:'duedate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'cldoc',index:'cldoc', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'text',index:'texxt', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'username',index:'username', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'currency',index:'currency', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'concode',index:'concode', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'region',index:'region', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'stat',index:'stat', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'process',index:'process', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'combination',index:'combination', width:60, sortable:true},
    {name:'comments',index:'comments', width:150, height:20, edittype:'textarea', sortable:false, editable: true,
            editoptions: {disabled: false, size:50, resizable:true}}
    ],
viewrecords: true
});


       $("#datagrid1").jqGrid({               ///////////////2nd Grid

            url: "service url",
            type: "GET",
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            datatype: "json",
            //colNames:['Id','MID','Status','DocNo','VendorID','InvoiceNo','VendorName','Amount','Type','DocDate','DueDate','ClDoc','Texxt','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Comb','Comments'],
            colNames:['Id','MID','Status','VendorID','VendorName','InvoiceNo','DocDate','Amount','DocNo','Type','DueDate','ClDoc','Text','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Process','Comb','Comments'],
            colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:50,sortable:true},
    {name:'mid',index:'mid', width:50, sortable:true},
    {name:'status',index:'status', width:70, sortable:true},
    {name:'vendorid',index:'vendorid', width:90, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'vendorname',index:'vendorname', width:170, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'invoiceno',index:'invoiceno', width:130, sortable:false,align:"left"},   
    {name:'docdate',index:'docdate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, sortable:false,align:"Right" },
    {name:'docno',index:'docno', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'typee',index:'typee', width:50, sortable:false},
    {name:'duedate',index:'duedate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'cldoc',index:'cldoc', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'text',index:'texxt', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'username',index:'username', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'currency',index:'currency', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'concode',index:'concode', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'region',index:'region', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'stat',index:'stat', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'process',index:'process', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'combination',index:'combination', width:60, sortable:true},
    {name:'comments',index:'comments', width:150, edittype:'textarea', sortable:false, editable: true,
            editoptions: {disabled: false, size:50, resizable:true}}
        ]
viewrecords: true
});

});
```

Comment: Seems really rediculous to initialize separate grids for the same page. There must be a way to load the parameters dynamically.